# Java: Where do I find sourcecode of WindowsAccessbridge?

Tags: java, c++, accessibility, java-access-bridge

I downloaded the Java JDK 7 source code from https://jdk7.java.net/source.html.
This is a 100 MB package containing nearly all the source code - except the part that I'm interested in.

The Java Access Bridge (JAB) consists mainly of `WindowsAccessBridge.dll` and `JavaAccessBridge.dll` which are running in different processes and doing the inter-process communication.

In the source code package exist these folders and files:

```
jdk\make\bridge\JavaAccessBridge\Files_cpp.gmk
jdk\make\bridge\JavaAccessBridge\Makefile
```

and

```
jdk\make\bridge\WindowsAccessBridge\Files_cpp.gmk
jdk\make\bridge\WindowsAccessBridge\Makefile
```

but all the cpp files are missing.

The file Files_cpp.gmk says:

```
FILES_cpp = \
    AccessBridgeJavaVMInstance.cpp \
    AccessBridgeMessageQueue.cpp \
    AccessBridgeMessages.cpp \
    AccessBridgeWindowsEntryPoints.cpp \
    WinAccessBridge.cpp \
    AccessBridgeDebug.cpp \
    AccessBridgeEventHandler.cpp
```

None of these CPP files exist in the ZIP package.

And the Makefile says:

```
VERSIONINFO_RESOURCE = $(CLOSED_PLATFORM_SRC)/native/sun/bridge/AccessBridgeStatusWindow.rc
```

What is `CLOSED_PLATFORM_SRC` ?

So, now you will tell me: "*Forget it! These files are not public.*"

BUT, in this article: [Not receiving callbacks from the Java Access Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161142/not-receiving-callbacks-from-the-java-access-bridge) Darren Ford writes that he has compiled a Debug version of the WindowsAccessBridge. This was in 2009. So some years ago the code was available.

Has anybody this code and can publish it for me? (I don't care if it is from an older JDK.) Or is it still available and I did not find it?

**NOTE:** Before JDK 7 the Accessbridge was not part of the JDK. It was a separate download that had to be installed manually. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm

Comment: It does not appear to be available in source form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is coming a little late, but hope this will help others. 
You will need to download the JDK 8 [source](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk). You can find the Windows Access Bridge code [under](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/tree/master/src/windows/native/sun/bridge)